# Error ObjectDataSource could not find a non-generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

My error:  ObjectDataSource 'dsGenre' could not find a non-generic method 'GetGenre' that has no parameters.

My code:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="genreList" style="float:left;" DataSourceID="dsGenre" DataTextField="Author_Name" DataValueField="title_id" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="dsGenre" SelectMethod="GetGenre" TypeName="libros" />
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlGenres" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:library %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:library.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="get_allGenres" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="genre_id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Why the error and how do I correct it?

Comment: Ok, I have to ask: do you have a non-generic method 'GetGenre' that has no parameters?

Comment: can you update the question with `GetGenre` code?

Comment: That is all the code that was on the page.  i am supposed to resolve the error.  t

Comment: The previous developer was trying to call a stored procedure that would list the title genres in acombo box from a call to the sql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to find the `libros` class and check if a GetGenre method exists anywhere inside of it. For all we know, it's possible that this "libros" isn't accessible here. If you can't find a GetGenre method, try creating it inside the libros class. You'll probably have some more coding to do to get data to pull back but at least it might get rid of your current error and getting you closer to your goal. There's [more information about ObjectDataSource here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectmethod.aspx)

Also, it could be that you need to put the fully qualified class name in. It's hard to say without seeing more of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the link about object data sources.  The other developer quitand since I know vb, the mgr thought I would be ableto quickly bang this out.  ha ha.  i have some reading to do.